# SQL Multiple Conditional Minimum Statements

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, minimum

So I have a table with the following columns

| Member | Version |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 18 |
| 3 | 316 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 40 |
| 1 | 316 |
| 3 | 65 |
| 2 | 27 |
| 3 | 65 |

I want to write an SQL to get the minimum value of "Member", subjected to the following constraints of "Version" (there are around 20 but just using three here):

```
Where Version between 15 and 20
Where Version in (40, 316)
Where Version between 65 and 66
```

So the output would look like

| Member | Version |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 1 | 316 |
| 2 | 18 |
| 3 | 316 |
| 3 | 65 |

I have this code in a temp table

```
Select Member, MIN(Version) as Minimum_Version from #Temp
    where Version between 15 and 20
    or Version in (40, 316)
        or Version between 65 and 66
    Group By Member;
```

I get the fact that my problem is in the Group By, as it is "rolling up" the "Member" column. I am using SQL Server v16 so there is no String_agg.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Edit: So I am getting an error Invalid Object Name 'Member'. Here is the updated Code:

``````
With #TempCTE_Model as(
Select Member, Version from #Temp
    where Version Between 15 and 20
        or Version in (40, 316)
        or Version Between 65 and 66)

Select distinct #TempCTE_Model.Member,
        SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ','+cast(#Temp.Version as varchar(100))  AS [text()]
            FROM HIC_NB #Temp
            WHERE #Temp.Member = #TempCTE_Model.Member
            ORDER BY #Temp.Member
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 2, 1000) [Version]
FROM Member #TempCTE_Model`````
``````

Comment: please add which rdms you are usind and which version as well

Answer (score 0):

first create `cte`

```
with a as(
Select a, b from #Temp
    where b between 15 and 20
    or b in (40, 316)
        or b between 65 and 66)
```

then use `For XML PATH` as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT a2.a, 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ','+cast(a1.b as varchar(100))  AS [text()]
            FROM a a1
            WHERE a1.a = a2.a
            ORDER BY a1.a
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 2, 1000) [b]
FROM a a2
```

Comment: without knowing wihich rdms he is using, it is hard to tell if it supports CTE

Comment: So I am getting an error "Invalid object name 'Member'.